# How do I change the Header's default selection color of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

In the picture above, the blue color made the header text invisible and I want to change it. It is the condition when a corresponding column's cell has been clicked on. Here, any one of cells with value 345 has been clicked.

My question is - How do I change this blue color? Perhaps it is the highlighted color.

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ?
```

[References on settings](https://gist.github.com/anytizer/65ffb17385a81c95ca38996e7ae47d81)

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking, so forgive me if it is not. The current code you have posted should work. In my tests, the command you referenced like… `dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Orange;` … works as expected. This will set the fore color to Orange for ALL the header cells. From what you describe, it sounds like you want to use the grid’s… `dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle`… `SelectionForeColor` and `SelectionBackColor`. This applies to the column “headers” when a cell in that column is selected.

Comment: Unfortunately, my tests showed that the “SelectionBackColor” works, however the “SelectionForeColor” does NOT work. In my research, it appears this may be a bug in the grid. I could NOT find conclusive evidence of this; however, it clearly did not work as described in the MS documentation and other posts. From this I am guessing you may have to create your own paint procedure for this, or, since we know the selection back color “does” work, an easier solution may be to simply change the back color to something that contrast better with the headers fore color.

Answer (score 1):

When the `SelectionMode` property of the DGV is set to `FullRowSelect`, selecting a cell *highlights* the column header of that cell. Normally, this doesn't affect the chosen colors for the cell because the BackColor of the header cell is fixed. However, because you have `EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false`, and you're changing the fore color of the header cell, you need to also change the back color of its selection.

You may use the [`DataGridViewCellStyle.SelectionBackColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.selectionbackcolor) property. For example:

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGray;
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but in VS 2022, it still ignores the value of datagridview.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor and still uses the value of datagridview.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor. The datagridview.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor and datagridview.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor works as expected